# how can we add KeyUp event for the LABEL controls

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any way to add KeyUp event for the LABEL control? Just like TextChanged event. We have found KeyUp Property for the TEXTBOX control. KeyUp property of the TEXTBOX control available on the "Property window", but for the LABEL control it is not available.

So, Please suggest me that how can we add KeyUp property on the LABEL control.

Thanks & Regards

pankajsingh

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you are trying to do.  Have you found a way for the Label control to have keyboard focus?

Comment: Unlike textbox, label can't take input focus. Thus capturing keyboard events in labels is meaningless.

Comment: What control has the focus on the form when you want this keyboard action to take place?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do this.  Label controls don't capture keyboard focus, so therefore, there aren't any keyboard events you can listen for.

Answer (score 1):

You can't even get focus on a label (it has no accessible `TabStop` property that you can set to `true`, and by default, it does not receive input).  Therefore, this question doesn't make any sense.  There's no way to get any key-related events from a label.

Answer (score 0):

As other's have pointed out, there is no `KeyUp` event for a `Label` control.

Having said that, you could use a `TextBox` under the hood and make it look like a `Label` and then wire up the `KeyUp` event.

Be sure to set these properties...

[image: TextBox Properties]

[image: TextBox Properties]

And here's what it would look like.

[image]